# My computer is always freezing, how do I fix it?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, dell, laptop, freeze

I am using a Dell Latitude E6500 on Ubuntu 16.04 with 2GB RAM.

The computer freezes often when running firefox and even running python.

Should I use a lighter OS like Lubuntu or are there any changes like swap RAM or eliminating unneeded programs that can free up some RAM? When i first start the computer it runs at less that 1 GB RAM.

Comment: 2G RAM might very well be your problem. How much swap do you have? Cheers, Al

Comment: ps: see <http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Dell/latitude-e6500> Cheers, Al

Comment: Swap is zero. Would that help? How do I turn it on?